# Passing arguments in super function in classes: is it needed?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, super

I was creating a function and forget to add all the instance variables in as arguments and it worked just fine, I thought that was necessarily, because I thought you were choosing what arguments in to inherit with that, but its seems to work with out it, so to reiterate, are they necessary and if so what purpose are they passed in for thanks

```
class Felidea{
    constructor(name,age,sex){
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
        this.sex=sex;
        this.hasRetractableClaws=true;
        this.hasNightVision=true;  //instance variables
    }
    static isSameSex(cat1,cat2){
        return cat1.sex===cat2.sex;
    }
    scratch(){
        console.log(this.name + ": scratch scratch scratch");
    }
    bite(){
        console.log(this.name + ": bite bite bite");
    }

}

class HouseCat extends Felidea {
    constructor(name, age, sex) {
        super(); // arguments missing, I commonly see this have the same  properties as the parent class
        //super(name, age, sex, hasRetractableClaws, hasNightVision) this is what I commonly see
    }
    purr(){
        console.log(this.name + ": purr purr purr");
    }
}

 let spots= new Felidea("spots", 4, "female"); // works fine and inherits the      
                                             //missing arguments variables
```

Comment: I don't see any arguments missing; your constructor asks for three and you pass it three. Am I missing something?

Comment: "JavaScript functions do not check the number of arguments received." https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp

Comment: I commonly see the super get the same arguments passed to it as the constructor, but it seems to work fine without them so I'm trying to understand the purpose of passing the the super function those arguments

Comment: But you are creating a new `Felidea`, not a new `HouseCat `, so `super` is not involved in your "test".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the arguments. Your test is not correctly done, as you do not create an instance of the extended class, but the base class.

If you change the last line, see what happens:

```js
class Felidea{
    constructor(name,age,sex){
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
        this.sex=sex;
        this.hasRetractableClaws=true;
        this.hasNightVision=true;  //instance variables
    }
    static isSameSex(cat1,cat2){
        return cat1.sex===cat2.sex;
    }
    scratch(){
        console.log(this.name + ": scratch scratch scratch");
    }
    bite(){
        console.log(this.name + ": bite bite bite");
    }

}

class HouseCat extends Felidea{
    constructor(name,age,sex){
        super(); // arguments missing, I commonly see this have the same  properties as the parent class
        //super(name,age,sex,hasRetractableClaws,hasNightVision) this is what I commonly see
    }
    purr(){
        console.log(this.name + ": purr purr purr");
    }
}

 let spots= new HouseCat("spots",4,"female"); // <--- !!!!!!!
 console.log(spots);
```

All these properties are now undefined.